# Unable to change background color of DataGridColumnHeader in DataGrid Winui3

Tags: winui-3

I am creating a WinUI3 project and using Datagrid from

```
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid
```

I am unable to change DataGridColumnHeader using Setter while Foreground changes perfectly fine. My Code :

```
 <controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
   <Style TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>       //This doesnt work                        
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> //This works
                     
   </Style>
                           
</controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Output

[image]

No matter what I do, the header background remains white. What should I do to change Column Header Background color?

**Edit**

I saw an issue on Github about it, but didn't make sense to me how to implement it !

```
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3393
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override these 3 colors:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="GreenishColor">#FF60B560</Color>
    <Color x:Key="YellowishColor">#FFFFF700</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BlueishColor">#FF00e5ff</Color>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="GreenishColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="YellowishColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="BlueishColor"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

you can also do this inside your `DataGrid` like this:

```xml
<controls:DataGrid>
    <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="GreenishColor">#FF60B560</Color>
        <Color x:Key="YellowishColor">#FFFFF700</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BlueishColor">#FF00e5ff</Color>
        <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="GreenishColor"/>
        <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="YellowishColor"/>
        <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="BlueishColor"/>
    </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: How to remove this line between columns?

Comment: how do give font style in the header?

Comment: how to increase the height of the header?

Comment: I guess you should ask these on a new question. I'm not sure if all of them are possible but I'll take a look at them.